# Is it possible to change value of props via vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

In the past, our small team have been using Adobe's Target to perform A/B testing.
Before Vue.js, our applications was relatively simple -- just plain vanilla JS. It was fairly straightforward to do any DOM manipulation (or any data manipulation) since not many things on our application's data was decoupled to anything.

As we are transitioning to Vue.js, the concept of modularizing into components and passing information via props would mean that we may not be able to change props directly from Target's perspective.

However, I noticed that Vue Devtools extension allows you to change the props directly.

Is it possible to do the same thing by vanilla JS?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? It’s a little confusing, why would you not be able to change props directly from the child component?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not natural to change properties from target component. In Vue.js the model is "Data down - Actions up". This means that you pass some data from parent component to child component and if the child component have to change something, it should emit an event and its parent component should listen for it and react to it. If you need flexibility and your data changes dynamically, you can pass objects via the props and also emit event with objects as payload. I think this is how you should approach the new implementation of your application from vanilla JS.